# QGIS 3 Select Lines That Touch A Point

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Using python I would like to iterate through a point layer and select from a line layer each line that touches a particular point. To try and familiarize myself with selecting items with python I'm just trying to write a script that selects lines that touch the selected point. This is what I have but I only get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'selectedFeatures'".

```
layer_select = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Points')
layer_to_select = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Lines')
for selected_feat in layer_select.selectedFeatures():
    to_select = []
    for feat_to_select in layer_to_select.getFeatures():
        if feat_to_select.geometry().intersects(selected_feat.geometry()):
            to_select.append(feat_to_select.id())
    layer_to_select.setSelectedFeatures(to_select)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little digging and I found what works.

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('point')
layer_select = layers[0] # first layer named LAYER_NAME.

layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('line')
layer_to_select = layers[0] # first layer named LAYER_NAME.

for f in layer_select.selectedFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    to_select = []
    for feat_to_select in layer_to_select.getFeatures():
        if feat_to_select.geometry().intersects(geom):
            to_select.append(feat_to_select.id())
    layer_to_select.selectByIds(to_select)
```